# Passing arguments to multiple tasks in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt 0.13.9, I want to be able to run a task which takes in arguments from the command line and then passes those arguments on to two other tasks.

My initial attempt was something along the lines of:

```
lazy val logTask = InputKey[Unit](...)
lazy val runTask = InputKey[Unit](...)

lazy val TestCase = config("testCase") extend Test

runTask in TestCase := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  runReg(args)
}.evaluated

logTask in TestCase := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  log(args)
}.evaluated    

def runReg(args: Seq[String]) = Def.taskDyn {
  val argString = args.mkString(" ")
  (logTask in TestCase).toTask(argString).value

  (testOnly in TestCase).toTask(s" $argString")
}

def log(args: Seq[String]) {
  (runMain in TestCase).toTask(s" LoggingClass $args.mkString(" ")")
}
```

But then it complains of an Illegal Dynamic Reference argString in `(logTask in TestCase).toTask(argsString).value`

I've also tried something like:

```
runTask in TestCase := {
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  log(args).value
  runReg(args).value
}
```

which also has an Illegal Dynamic Reference for args.

Is there any way of passing in parsed arguments into two tasks and run one after the other?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you post your entire build file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thejonathanwong/8757accdeabb568ae2b8

The logging class is in a jar that is added to any project that uses this plugin.

Comment: It looks like this may be a [bug as of sbt 13.1](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1041)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning `args.mkString(" ")` to a variable, just pass it without assigning to any variable like below:

```
(logTask in TestCase).toTask(args.mkString(" ")).value
```

**Update 1:**

This kind of issues can also be sorted out with [lazy initialization in sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html#How+build.sbt+defines+settings). So, try something like below:

```
lazy val argString = args.mkString(" ")
(logTask in TestCase).toTask(argString).value
```